# Parse.com Framework Sort Date Next Birthday

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, ios8

Need to sort on iOS by date using Parse.com but I need to order them based on the next birthday for a specific person. I tried to add the day and month with the current or next year and that helped but that will be a manual process, any recommendations to do this in an automated way.

As a side note I want to implement it in swift

Thanks all in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exact code will depend on your personal setup (I can imagine you've made a subclass of `PFObject` or similar), but try to experiment with the following code. I've also made another function called `filterFriendsAfterBirthdays` that might be useful for somebody reading this post.

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  ParseFun
//
//  Created by Stefan Veis Pennerup on 20/06/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Kumuluzz. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        createDummyData()
        queryForFriends() {
            println("Unsorted birthdays: \($0)")
            println("Sorted birthdays: \(self.filterFriendsAfterBirthdays($0))")
            println("Closets upcoming birthday: \(self.filterFriendsBasedOnClosetsUpcomingBirthday($0))")
        }
    }

    func createDummyData() {
        for var i = 0; i < 25; i++ {
            let myFriend = PFObject(className: "Friends")
            let interval = Double(arc4random_uniform(UInt32.max))
            myFriend["birthday"] = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: interval)
            myFriend.saveInBackground()
        }
    }

    func queryForFriends(completionHandler: ([PFObject]) -> ()) {
        let friendsQuery = PFQuery(className: "Friends")
        friendsQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (result, error) in
            if (error != nil) { return }
            let pfArray = result as! [PFObject]
            completionHandler(pfArray)
        }
    }

    func filterFriendsAfterBirthdays(friends: [PFObject]) -> [PFObject] {
        return friends.sorted {
            return ($0["birthday"] as! NSDate).compare($1["birthday"] as! NSDate) == .OrderedAscending
        }
    }

    func filterFriendsBasedOnClosetsUpcomingBirthday(friends: [PFObject]) -> [PFObject] {
        let cal = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()

        // Specifies the day unit
        let dayUnit: NSCalendarUnit = .CalendarUnitDay

        // Gets todays year
        let today = NSDate()
        let yearUnit: NSCalendarUnit = .CalendarUnitYear
        let yearToday = cal.components(yearUnit, fromDate: today)

        // Combined days and year units
        let combinedUnits: NSCalendarUnit = .CalendarUnitYear | .CalendarUnitDay

        return friends.sorted {
            // Gets the birthday components since today
            // Also uses the year unit to ensure that the day will be between -365 and 365
            let birth1Components = cal.components(combinedUnits, fromDate: today, toDate: ($0["birthday"] as! NSDate), options: nil)
            let birth2Components = cal.components(combinedUnits, fromDate: today, toDate: ($1["birthday"] as! NSDate), options: nil)

            // Updates the days to a positive integer
            if (birth1Components.day < 0) { birth1Components.day += 365 }
            if (birth2Components.day < 0) { birth2Components.day += 365 }

            return birth1Components.day <= birth2Components.day
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If my answer to your question was helpful and was fulfilling, then please accept it as the answer to your post to indicate towards other users that your issue has been resolved :)
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: It works nice, still need to get it to work on a PFQueryTableViewController but you pointed me in the right direction. If I cant get it to work I will use a plain tableview instead. Thanks a lot